# How to add a image to SQL Database from Java

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jdbc, netbeans-7

I am making a software and I want to give an option to add a picture.

I am using Netbeans 7.4 , mySQL server 5.1, And Query Browser 1.2

I want to know how to configure the database and how to develop the feature for adding a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to store images in a mySql db using data types such as LONGBLOB

```
img LONGBLOB not null
```

To do this in Java you want to do something like the following to get the byte string of the image:

```
File image = new File(imageName);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(image);

WritableRaster writableRaster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
DataBufferByte dataBufferByte = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
```

You can then add it to your database using JDBC.

NOTE: Although I have given you the answer on how to do this, I would not recommend implementing it in this way as it is bad practice. Images can get very large and you might find your db filling up very quickly.

Instead, a more efficient solution would be to store the images in directories alongside your code, and store paths to the images in the database as simple text strings.

Comment: -there's nothing like 'raster' in netbeans. but I found 'Raster'. Even if i get a error, it says, "non-static method getDataBuffer() cannot be referenced from a static context".